# Sum of amount returning 0 instead of actual sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the below query wherein the sum(Amount) field is returning me 0 instead of the actual sum value.

Data type of the amount field is decimal(15,2)

**Query:**

```
SELECT Period
        ,count(DISTINCT Trans_Date) as [Date_count]
        ,count(*) as Row_No
        ,sum([Amount]) as [Amount_Value]
        ,count(*)-count([Amount]) as [Amount_null]
        FROM table1 
    GROUP BY Period
    ORDER BY Period
```

**Result:**

```
Period  Date_count  Row_No  Amount_Value    Amount_null

2014/03 31          15486   0.00            0
```

Would you suggest any possible reason why? Thanks.

Table Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    [Period] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [Account] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [Trans_Date] [date] NULL,
    [Amount] [decimal](15, 2) NULL
)
```

**Sample Data :**

```
Period  Account Trans_Date  Amount
2014/03 001234  2014-03-01  4517.45
2014/03 001234  2014-03-01  2120.77
2014/03 001234  2014-03-01  3115.69
2014/03 001245  2014-03-01  1803.78
2014/03 001245  2014-03-01  596.33
2014/03 001245  2014-03-01  null
```

Comment: Please post schema and sample data.

Comment: Also, please post the results of the SELECT query when you remove the `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: count(*)-count([Amount]) as [Amount_null] will always produce 0 because you are getting the same count values.

Comment: @SaifKhan - Yes, count(*)-count([Amount]) as [Amount_null] will always produce 0. I agree. I am worried about the sum([Amount]) as [Amount_Value] part which is returning 0 here.

Comment: Doesn't look like sum of amount equals 0 to me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6bcaf/1/0

Comment: use `sum(Isnull([Amount], 0))` or `sum(COALESCE([Amount], 0))`

Comment: Mind editting your data set to include a null amount?   My guess is lack of null handling on the sum is causing this, without a null in your data set, the issue won't reproduce.

Comment: @cha you beat me to it....this is also COALESCE.

Comment: The problem isn't `NULL` in a `sum()`.  `sum()` ignores `NULL` values.

Answer (score 2):

The logical conclusion is that the sum of `Amount` over your data is, in fact, 0.00.

The data you have as a sample, the correct result is returned:

```
PERIOD  DATE_COUNT  ROW_NO  AMOUNT_VALUE  AMOUNT_NULL
2014/03 1           6       12154.02      1
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/311672/1) is a SQL Fiddle.

Just to correct some misconceptions from the comments.

- NULL values are ignored in `SUM()` (and `AVG()` and `MIN()` and `MAX()` too)
- `count(*)-count([Amount])` is being used correctly to count the number of `NULL` values (although I prefer the more explicit formulation of `sum(case when Amount is NULL then 1 else 0 end)`).